# How to show the history records up to financial year end day. POWER BI

Tags: database, powerbi

I have a data set like this

| Year | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2021 | 4 |
| 2022 | 5 |
| 2022 | 6 |

I want show all the history records up to the selected year in Slicer:

- 2020
- 2021
- 2022

For example, if I select *2020*, it should show:

| Year | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |

And if I select *2021*, it should show:

| Year | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2021 | 4 |

If I select *2022*, it should show:

| Year | Records |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2021 | 4 |
| 2022 | 5 |
| 2022 | 6 |

I am very appreciated if you have some ideas for me.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a "less than or equal to" [Numeric Range Slicer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-slicer-numeric-range?tabs=powerbi-desktop) on the Year

[image]

Comment: How about the Slicer do not has a Numeric Number? just the dropdown list

Comment: That's the only built-in slicer that behaves like that.  You could use a "is less than or equal to" filter instead.